# PHP accessing object -> array which is filled with objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

Once more I have a little question. It's just a small thing but I don't get it.

```
$test[] = $theImage2 -> data;
```

Structure is the following: $theImage is a object. It has data which is an array holding objects. I try to fill $test wit the objects from data... But it doesn't work.

Edit:
Well I forget to say that I get the object from a doctrine sql query.

```
 $theImage2 = Doctrine_Core::getTable("EFImage")->findBy('name',$this -> _data['name']);
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Add the data of `$theImage2`.

Comment: post your object structure ?

Comment: Please show object structure. means the data of `$theImage2`

Comment: Well I forget to say that I get the object from a doctrine sql query. 

     $theImage2 = Doctrine_Core::getTable("EFImage")->findBy('name',$this -> _data['name']);

Comment: show that in your question and write what ever in your question, but not in comment.specially code. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found the solution. I had to access them with 
     $duplicateImg = $theImage2[0] -> name;